# Get duplicated results in array_rand

Tags: php

```
<?php

class GenCrypt
{
    public function generate()
    {
        $hashSource = array_merge(range('A', 'Z'), range('a', 'z'), range(0, 9));
        $hashRandom = array_rand($hashSource, 12);
        shuffle($hashRandom);
        return implode(',', $hashRandom);
    }
}

$gen = new GenCrypt;
$count = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $count[] = $gen->generate();
}

var_dump(count($count));
var_dump(count(array_unique($count)));
```

I want to generate non-repetitive serial, so I use `array_rand` and `shuffle` to avoid duplicated data, but still got regular duplicated result, how to make it work?

Comment: What is your original task? Do you need just 1000 unique strings or you need unique strings every time over all ever generated strings?

Comment: Should the serial be random? It would be easier to generate non duplicates if you generate them in an order..

Comment: My original task is to generate 1000000 non duplicates serial number

Answer (score 1):

[`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) does not provide unique elements, it just picks up one or more randoms. You need to use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to retrieve uniques. Also, shuffling the randoms is not necessary.

The summing up:

```
// $hashRandom = array_rand($hashSource, 12); // no promise on uniqueness

while(count($hashRandom = array_unique(array_rand($hashSource, count($hashSource)))) < 12) {
  /* insuccessful try, repeat */
}

// here $hashRandom has 12 uniques
```

In general, the first attempt should return `12` unique elements out of `count($hashSource)` randomly pulled. If not, the statement will be reevaluated until `12` are yielded. Hope it helps.

Comment: Without using `shuffle()`, `array_rand()` returns an ordered list. This reduces the possible outcomes from [1.03e21](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=62p12) to [2.2e12](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=62c12)

Comment: @Phylogenesis Would you mind to drop a proof reference?

Comment: Both figures have Wolfram Alpha links showing the calculation. The 62 comes from the total number of elements (26 * 2 + 10).